# Delete row when update sets column to specific value

Tags: sql, triggers, mysql-5.5

Due to poor coding, our site has a heart attack when any user tries to delete a contact category from the back end of Joomla (SQL 5.5). Instead of deleting it, it updates the "published" column to -2 (where 1 is published, and -1 is not published). Unable to find the source that causes this, we've almost imediately moved to trying to create a trigger to delete the category entirely.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `PermaDelete`
AFTER UPDATE
ON `nac_categories`

FOR EACH ROW
    DELETE FROM nac_categories WHERE (NEW.published = -2);
```

The error I received was

```
Error
Can't update table 'nac_categories' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger. SQL=UPDATE `nac_categories` SET published = -2 WHERE (lft > 0 AND rgt < 0) OR id = 36
```

Basically, I just want to delete the category when published is updated to -2

Comment: SQL server or mysql ?

Comment: Your code is like mysql syntax.

Comment: What do you get if you do a `DELETE FROM NEW WHERE (NEW.published = -2);`

Comment: If this was truly SQL Server and not mysql, the way out would be to have the trigger raise an event, and have the event fire a delete.  But your error message AND your SQL syntax strongly imply this is mysql and not SQL Server.

Comment: This is most definitely mysql syntax, and the error seems to occur because it is trying to affect the database during the update process, rather than post like i had hoped. Still very early in trying to create triggers and what not, but I'll look into creating events and see what solutions I can find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading up, I cannot create an EVENT from within a TRIGGER, and I cannot manipulate the table (through deletion) in this manner, as it attempts to manipulate the table in a way that prevents the initial event from firing. I could, however, create an event that ran every 5 seconds or so to clear out -2's, but it would be cleaner if I just dig into the php doing the update and change it. Lot harder, but I'll keep an ear out in here just in case someone knows of a method.